# angularjs Rest API

Tags: angularjs, api, rest, routes

I've read up many articles on angularjs and REST but could not found any solution. Through java script I am calling api method, which is routed method as:

```
[Route("api/Comments/{docId}/comment/{revId}/get/{size}/getNumber/{number}")]
[HttpPost]

public IEnumerable<Student> Get(int docId,int revId,int size, int number)
{

      // loadienter code hereng list here

     return list.ToList();
}

//java script code
var url='api/students/' + docId + '/student/' + revId + '/get/'+size+'/getNumber/'+number';
$http.get(url).success(function (response) {
                    if (callback) callback(response.result);
                };
```

But the method in controller class is not executing..How to solve this issue? P
Please give me some  suggestions..

Comment: How is this related to angular?

Comment: I'm using $http.get.

Comment: But where are you calling $http get? Can you show us your full angularJS controller or service where you are doing this?

Answer (score 0):

If in your angular controller you have just that code for the call to the api it looks like when you are constructing your `url` variable you haven't included on the front of it what the domain is that you are hitting. such as `http://localhost/` if your debugging it locally.

Also your route is defined to start as `api/comments/` on your WebApi however in your javascript url you have `api/students/`